# Running a cronjob on each instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to try out dropwizard-metrics + graphite.

For order to this to work out i need to run a job regular (e.g. each 5:th second) that sends metrics from the instance to the graphite server.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The [java documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) and [python documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) for Cron in App Engine says that the minimal interval in App Engine is configurable in 'minutes'. Thus the simple answer would be: No you cannot schedule a job *every 5 seconds*.

**However...**

Knowing that tasks queue tasks can run up to 10 Minutes ([see deadlines](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push)) you could manually schedule a task every (let's say) 5 minutes and handle the 5 second interval yourself in your servlet (or whatever it is called in python).

I'm just saying it is possible to use suche short intervals. You should really avoid a crutch like that. This kind of behaviour will eat through your quota and make your app expensive really fast.

**Edit:**

Since the title of the question asks for running jobs in specific instances:

As Dmitry pointed out and as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) it is possible to address specific instances when using *manual* or *basic* scaling with modules. Instances are anonymous when using *automatic* scaling and thus cannot be addressed. It seems this feature is only documented and available for app engine modules.

Comment: You have a point but lets if I change my question tu running the upload job each minut the question is still valid. Is it possible to run a cronjob on each instance.

Comment: First off, thanks for downvoting a perfectly valid answer. I posted the relevant documentation links that allow triggering of jobs with cron. Using cron is how you'd do it. I simply wanted to point out that you should avoid such short intervals because it'll eat through your quota.

Comment: The question was about running jobs on each instance. Nothing in your answer adressess  that question.

Comment: I understand. My answer did not refer to the title of your question but to the content, which does not contain that requirement (not clearly anyway). I also updated my answer accordingly, saying that this is not possible.

Comment: You can execute jobs on a `version` or a `module` but not on specific instances that are running said `version` or `module`s. The whole point of app engine is to not worry about server instances so they don't give you explicit access to them.

Comment: Well you can run code on specific instance with Manual or Basic scaling, but not with Automatic.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi Please elaborate. I don't see how it is possible to perform a task regularly in a specific instance of the app and in a useful way. If set to manual scaling and a single instance, you only ever have one instance, okay. But with basic scaling you have an instance per request, thus your measurement would only measure itself and nothing else.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you *can* run specific task on specific instance, not only on specific version/module. From docs: ```Instances are addressable at URLs with the form: http://instance.version.module.app_id.appspot.com`. If you have set up a wildcard subdomain mapping for a custom domain, you can also address a module or any of its instances via a URL of the form `http://module.domain.com` or `http://instance.module.domain.com`. You can reliably cache state in each instance and retrieve it in subsequent requests.```

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi I updated my answer and linked the respective documentation page. Thanks. I somehow doubt that this is what Gunnar was looking for, but for the sake of completeness i added it.